# Navigation Arrow Not updating: Navigation arrow not rotating at high speed navigation

Tags: android, skmaps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxCcZ.png)

In the image above as you can see my navigation arrow is not pointing in the correct direction in which i am driving. This issue always occurs when i am driving at high speed.What can be done to remove this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for above is easy i missed it:

```
mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowPositions(true);
```

And to apply logic of if else lader to and provide below

```
 mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.HISTORIC_POSITIONS);
 mapView.getMapSettings().setHeadingMode(SKMapSettings.SKHeadingMode.ROUTE);
```

Thank you for your views.